# How to create Microsoft Lync profile integration with SharePoint 2010 Contact List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lync

I have a SharePoint 2010 site and my company also uses Microsoft Lync. I am creating a contact list in the sharepoint site and would like to have the person's lync profile as the listing in the contact list. Since we use photos in our Lync profiles and also are mandated to keep our Lync profiles up to date at all times I would minimize the maintenance int he SharePoint page where my contact list is displayed. How can I integrate and get what I want done out of these two application?

Answer (score 0):

Since all Lync profile data is integrated with AD so you can sync all these AD fields in SharePoint and once that's done you can have Lync profile information SharePoint UserProfile .

Comment: I appreciate the info but you did not list the steps on how to do what you stated. Can you please submit those steps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: its all available over internet just need to take help of google , i have found one link for you http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049(v=office.14).aspx